# A test that consider approximate values, not strictly the value

Tags: r

I'm wondering if a function that I could use to check several vectors that should sum up to **near** 1 already exists. Ideally, the numbers should sum up to 1, but I would not bother if it's not too far from it. 
If I use `if(y == 1)` or `if(y <= 1)`, I'll get too much mismatches, which are not that significant because the differences are due to rounding decimals.
I came up with rounding the vector to zero decimals, but I'd love to be able to apply some sort of tolerance from the ideal sum, like 1% or .05

```
y = c(.4965, .2666, .115, .0750, .0316, .0147)

> isTRUE(round(sum(y),0)<=1)
[1] TRUE

> isTRUE(round(sum(y),0)<=.99)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: There's probably a very thorough way to do this with significant digits, if it's worth the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `all.equal` function and specify the tolerance you want:

```
all.equal(sum(y), 1, tolerance = 0.05)
#[1] TRUE
```